# When utilizing chart.chartstyle = 248 how do I turn off all caps in the axes title?

Tags: vba, excel, charts, fonts, axes

### Problem

I want to be able to effectively uncheck the box for all caps [Font Properties Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNevC.jpg) in VBA on an excel chart axis label / title.

---

### What I have tried

For excel, the option for all caps as a member of characters or font does not seem to be available within charts.

Furthermore, changing only the text using something like Upper, Ucase, or LCase does not work.

---

### Some Code

I have included my code where I am building the chart. You can see in the comments some of my attempts to change the property of allcaps. Using vba in excel with some thing similar to:

```
 With newChart
    'If put an if statement to see if name already exists, try catch case would be good too
    .Name = UsrFrm2.titleTxt.Text
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
    '.CategoryLabelLevel = xlCategoryLabelLevelCustom

    'using preselected formatting for chart
    .ChartStyle = 248
    .ChartColor = 10

    'Labeling
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = Me.titleTxt.Text
    .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlPrimary) = True
    .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlSecondary) = True
    .HasAxis(xlValue, xlPrimary) = True
    .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
    '.Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).CategoryType = xlAutomatic
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    '.Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary).HasTitle = True
    '.Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Loss Tangent (tand)"
    .HasLegend = True
    '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = 1000000
   ' .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaxiumScale = 1800000000
End With
```

or something such as this:

```
With newChart
    'trying to change the axis titles to turn off all caps. I cannot figure out how at the moment, will have to do by hand.
        'Plotyy format
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = UsrFrm2.XALabel.Value
        '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Bold = False
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
        '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Allcaps = False
        '.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Font.Allcaps = False
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = UsrFrm2.XSMin.Value
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = UsrFrm2.XSMax.Value
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
        If Me.X_MHz.Value = True Then
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).DisplayUnit = xlCustom
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).DisplayUnitCustom = 1000000#
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasDisplayUnitLabel = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).DisplayUnitLabel.Caption = "MHz"
        ElseIf Me.X_GHz.Value = True Then
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).DisplayUnit = xlCustom
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).DisplayUnitCustom = 1000000000#
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasDisplayUnitLabel = True
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).DisplayUnitLabel.Caption = "GHz"
        Else
            .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).DisplayUnit = xlNone
        End If
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinimumScale = UsrFrm2.YSMin.Value
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = UsrFrm2.YSMax.Value
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MajorUnitIsAuto = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MinorUnitIsAuto = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
End With
```

Suggestions Please.

---

---

Do or Do Not, There is no Try --Yoda, Jedi Master

Answer (score 0):

`Chart`s are not `Excel` alone but across all office applications. So their objects are also not native `Excel` objects. `Allcaps`, `Smallcaps`, ... are members of the `Font2` object. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863038%28v=office.14%29.aspx

To get the `Font2` object is sometimes a little bit tricky.

Assuming we have the following chart sheet:

[image]

Then the following `VBA` should do:

```
Sub test()

 Dim oChart As Chart
 Dim oFont2 As Font2

 Set oChart = ActiveChart

 With oChart
  Set oFont2 = .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
  oFont2.Allcaps = msoTrue
  oFont2.Allcaps = msoFalse
  oFont2.Smallcaps = msoTrue
  oFont2.Smallcaps = msoFalse

 End With

End Sub
```